# Equivalent of Lodash _.set() in Underscore.js

Tags: javascript, lodash, javascript-objects, underscore.js

is there some equivalent of [Lodash _.set()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#set) in [Underscore.js](https://underscorejs.org)?

Or maybe some one-liner code for adding nested properties to Objects?

Comment: https://youmightnotneed.com/lodash/ , it might be usefull. This website show a native JS solution for almost every lodash function

Comment: There isn't a `_.set()` in Underscore, although I don't know why. You can see the duplicate question for JS alternatives. Or you can also get the Lodash implementation.

Comment: What's wrong with the one in lodash?

Comment: @AdilBimzagh I assume OP doesn't want to add it as a dependency, since they already use Underscore.

Comment: @VLAZ Yeah probably.